# C# Inheritance. Console is not opening

Tags: c#, inheritance, console

I have two classes named car and vehicle. I inherited the car class from the vehicle class. I'm trying to run it in program.cs. But the console is opening and closing. Console.Read(); I did but it still behaves the same. It doesn't give an error either. I did not understand the reason. I am sharing the codes.

Program.cs

```
namespace _4_Encapsulation_and_Properties
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Car myCar = new Car();
            myCar.Honk();
            Console.WriteLine("My car brand is: " + myCar.brand + "My car model is: " + myCar.model);
            Console.Read();
        }

    }
}
```

Car.cs

```
namespace _4_Encapsulation_and_Properties
{
    class Car :  Vehicle // Child class
    {
        public string model = "Corolla";
    }
}
```

Vehicle.cs

```
namespace _4_Encapsulation_and_Properties
{
    class Vehicle // base Class
    {
        public string brand = "Toyota";
        public void Honk()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Düüd , Düüd!");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly for me. Try placing a breakpoint on the line `Car car = new Car();` and stepping into and through each class one line at a time, that might at least shed some light on which line might be causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote my codes in the wrong project. I created a different project for Inheritance, but I created my classes in the project I created for Encapsulation. It did not work because the Inheritance project was selected as the Startup project and this project was empty.